# Proving (2,5) is an open set?

Tags: real-analysis

I'm given the following definition of an open set: 
A set $X \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is open iff for all $x \in X$ there exists $d>0$ such that $(x-d,x+d) \subseteq X$.

I'm given the following proof: 
Let $x \in (2,5)$.
Let $d$ be the minimum of $5-x$ and $x-2$.
Then $(x-d,x+d) \subseteq (2,5)$.
So for all $x \in (2,5)$ there exists $d>0$ such $(x-d,x+d) \subseteq (2,5)$.
So $(2,5)$ is an open set.
Q.E.D

I understand that we have to choose $d$ so it depends on $x$, but I don't understand why we should choose the minimum of $5-x$ and $x-2$ and how this justifies the next step?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take $x \in (2,5)$. The values $5-x$ and $x-2$ are the distances of $x$ from $5$ and $2$ respectively. Hence if you take a $d$ smaller or equal than both of these values (or, equivalently, smaller or equal than their minimum), you can be sure that $(x-d,x+d) \subseteq (2,5)$, which proves what you wanted to show, since $x \in (x-d,x+d)$.

Comment: +1 for "smaller or equal". It is fine to choose "equal" (as the proof does) when you can, but you can never go wrong by choosing "smaller" in a situation like this. This is good to remember for times when it is hard to calculate the diameter of a neighborhood that will just exactly "fit"; often, it's a lot easier to just choose something that you know is smaller than necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Understanding a proof is the first step to writing your own, so good for you in scrutinizing this.

Draw a picture of the real line and the open set $(2,5)$.  Pick a point $x$ in this interval and some generic $d > 0$.  What does the set $(x-d,x+d)$ look like?  What are the conditions on $d$ that guarantee that $(x-d,x+d)$ is contained in $(2,5)$?